# Chaining promises with JavaScript Trello API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, promise, trello

I'm trying to use the JavaScript Trello API to compile a list of cards that can be from any of the users boards that fall under any list with the name "todo".

I successfully was able to get an array of list ID's from all boards with the name "todo".

```
...

}).then(function(list_data) {

        console.log("List Data", list_data);
        console.log("List Data Length", list_data.length);

        var cards_arr = [];

        $.each(list_data, function(index, value) {

            Trello.get("/lists/" + value.id + "/cards?fields=name,shortUrl")
            .then(function(cards) {

                $.each(cards, function(index, card) {
                    cards_arr.push(card.id);
                })

            })

        })

        console.log("Cards Array", cards_arr);

        return cards_arr;

    })
```

When I look at the console log where it's showing my "list_data" variable I get an array of 6 items, but for some reason the length of the array is equal to 0 and doesn't allow me to loop through the "empty" array.

[Console Log SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEse0.png)

I feel that I may not be using the Trello API in the most effective way, so I will go ahead and post the full code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
    var boards_arr = [];

    // ==== LOOP THROUGH BOARDS
    Trello.get("/member/me/boards?fields=name,id,idOrganization")
    .then(function(boards) {

        $.each(boards, function(index, board) {
            if (board.idOrganization != "5112df8dad3201247401349e") return;
            boards_arr.push(board.id);
        });

        return boards_arr;

    }).then(function(board_data) {

        var lists_arr = [];

        console.log("Board Data", board_data);

        $.each(board_data, function(index, value) {

            Trello.get("/boards/" + value + "/lists?fields=id,name")
            .then(function(lists) {

                $.each(lists, function(index, list) {

                    var listName = list.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
                    if (listName != "todo") return;

                    lists_arr.push(list.id);
                });

            });

        });

        return lists_arr;

    }).then(function(list_data) {

        console.log("List Data", list_data);
        console.log("List Data Length", list_data.length);

        var cards_arr = [];

        $.each(list_data, function(index, value) {

            Trello.get("/lists/" + value.id + "/cards?fields=name,shortUrl")
            .then(function(cards) {

                $.each(cards, function(index, card) {
                    cards_arr.push(card.id);
                })

            })

        })

        console.log("Cards Array", cards_arr);

        return cards_arr;

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running an asynchronous operation (`Trello.get`) inside your `$.each` callback, the elements won't be added to the array until after these have completed, which is *after* `$.each` returns. So no elements have been added by the time you call `console.log(cards_arr)`.

What you should do instead, is to store the promises you get from `Trello.get` in an array, then call `Promise.all` to wait for all to complete, and *then* you build the `cards_arr` array when you have all the results. Since this separates the asynchronous and synchronous operations, you can be sure that cards_arr is actually complete when you call `console.log` afterwards.

```js
promise
  .then(function(list_data) {
    console.log("List Data", list_data);
    console.log("List Data Length", list_data.length);

    // do all operations and store results in an array
    var resultPromises = list_data.map(function(value) {
      return Trello.get("/lists/" + value.id + "/cards?fields=name,shortUrl")
    });

    // wait for all operations to complete
    return Promise.all(resultPromises);
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    // create cards_arr from results
    var cards_arr = [];
    $.each(results, function(index, cards) {
      $.each(cards, function(index, card) {
        cards_arr.push(card.id);
      });
    });

    // this should print the correct array
    console.log("Cards Array", cards_arr);

    return cards_arr;
  })
```